# How to configure HAproxy to redirect multiple domain

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

i need configure HAproxy to redirect multiple domain with SSL, i need redirect in this way:

```
www.foo.com redirect to ip_other_webserver:81
www.bar.com redirect to ip_other_webserver:82
www.zoo.com redirect to ip_other_webserver:8080
```

I do not know HAproxy, in the past i did the same configuration with nginx but i also need the load balancer. I can not find a configuration example.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try with DNS?

Comment: Because i need connect to other ports, not http/s ports, and need a load balancer

Comment: load balancing is when requesting a single domain you resolve (with some strategy) to one ip address from a pool; in this case you have three different domains with three service port, i don't see where the load balancing should happen

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned previously this is not really load balancing, but it's possible.

Try something like:

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    # urls
    acl host_foo hdr(host) -i www.foo.com
    acl host_bar hdr(host) -i www.bar.com
    acl host_zoo hdr(host) -i www.zoo.com
    # clusters
    use_backend foo_cluster if host_foo
    use_backend bar_cluster if host_bar
    use_backend zoo_cluster if host_zoo

backend foo_cluster
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option forwardfor
        server server1 ip_other_webserver:81 check

backend bar_cluster
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option forwardfor
        server server1 ip_other_webserver:82 check

backend zoo_cluster
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option forwardfor
        server server1 ip_other_webserver:8080 check
```